# Magento module setup resource namespace

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

Could someone explain how or if namespaces can be used in Magento module setup resources? I see a lot of tutorials saying to use the `<modulename_setup>` format, but somehow, the `mana_core` module managed to use `mana_core_setup` instead of `core_setup`. I tried doing the same thing, but I couldn't get it to work. I'm trying to create a project module, but I'd like to namespace it with the company name to minimize collisions. Should this be possible? Or did Mana work some extra magic behind the scenes? (FYI, this is on Magento 1.7.0.2.)

```
<!-- recommended style
     http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources -->
<resources>
    <weblog_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Magentotutorial_Weblog</module>
            <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
        </setup>
    </weblog_setup>
</resources>

<!-- app/code/local/Mana/Core/etc/config.xml -->
<resources>
    <mana_core_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Mana_Core</module>
        </setup>
    </mana_core_setup>
</resources>
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first link in the comment of your provided example explains that you can use pretty much any name you want - `modulename_setup` is merely a convention of how to make it easier for everyone involved to understand what and where it it. So you are entirely free to use `vendor_module_setup` format if you wish.

However it is worth a re-consideration why is it that you want a vendor-prefixed resource. In general resources should be something that is shared among modules in the system and should usually NOT be "owned" by a single module. This is, however, a rule of thumb, so if you have valid reasons (i.e. your resource is genuinely non-reusable in any way anywhere anyhow) then go on and create a prefixed one.